# Azure Web App. Free is faster than Basic and Standard?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure

I have a C# MVC application with a WCF service running on Azure. First of it was of course hosted on the free version, but as I had that one running smoothly I wanted to try and see how it ran on either Basic or Standard, which as far as I know should be dedicated servers.

To my surprise the code ran significantly slower once it was changed from Free to either Standard or Basic. I chose the smallest instance, but still expected them to perform better than the Free option?

From my performance logging I can see that the code that runs especially slow is something that is started as async from Task.Run. Initially it was old school Thread.Start() but considered whether this might spawn it in some lower priority thread and therefore changed it to Task.Run - without this changing anything - so perhaps it has nothing to do with it - but it might, so now you know.

The code that runs really slow basically works on some XML document, through XDocument, XElement etc. It loops through, has some LINQ etc. but nothing too fancy. But still it is 5-10 times slower on Basic and Standard as on the Free version? For the exact same request the Free version uses around 1000ms where as Basic and Standard uses 8000-10000ms?

In each test I have tried 5-10 times but without any decrease in response-times. I thought about whether I need to wait some hours before the Basic/Standard is fully functional or something like that, but each time I switch back, the Free version just outperforms it from the get-go.

Any suggestions? Is the Free version for some strange reason more powerful than Basic or Standard or do I need to configure something differently once I get up and running on Basic or Standard?

Comment: My guess is MS wants to make a good impression so the free tier is pretty snappy for a small amount of users/resources.  This guy says he hit a pretty big wall at 20 concurrent users with free: http://www.microsofttrends.com/2014/12/27/azure-web-sites-performance-analysis-hosting-plans-compared/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had actually been looking for some straight up comparison of the different options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notable difference between the Free and Basic/Standard tiers is that Free uses an undisclosed number of shared cores, whereas Basic/Standard has a defined number of CPU cores (1-4 based on how much you pay). Related to this is the fact that Free is a shared instance while Basic/Standard is a private instance.

My best guess based on this that since the Free servers you would be on house multiple different users and applications, they probably have pretty beef specs. Their CPUs are probably 8-core Xeons and there might even be multiple CPUs. Most likely, Azure isn't enforcing any caps but rather relying on quotas (60 CPU minutes / day for the Free tier) and overall demand on the server to restrict CPU use. In other words, if your site is the only one that happens to be doing anything at the moment (unlikely of course, but for the sake of example), you could be potentially utilizing all 8+ cores on the box, whereas when you move over to Basic/Standard you are hard-limited to 1-4. Processing XML is actually very CPU heavy, so this seems to line up with my assumptions.

More than likely, this is a fluke. Perhaps your residency is currently on a relatively newly provisioned server that hasn't been fill up with tenants yet. Maybe you just happen to be sharing with tenants that aren't doing much. Who knows? But, if the server is ever actually under real load, I'd imagine you'd see a much worse response time on the Free tier than even Basic/Standard.

Comment: That might be a very plausible explanation. I tried scaling the Standard to Medium and Large which then gave somewhat the same performance as the Free option. As a combination of your answer and the link from the comment below my initial question, I tried the Shared option, which actually gives the best performance I have seen. Of course as you suggest, my times may vary depending on how much the shared(both in the Free and Shared option) servers are loaded by other sites running on them.